# MVC3 - Create a selectable list (see details)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and SQL 2008r2. I am building a office pool application using MVC3 best practices, so I split it up into the 3 sections: project.domain, project.unittests and project.webui. Here is my challenge.
I would like to build a list like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Week 1 - 10/17/2011 - 10/24/2011
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuesday, 6:15pm [TeamSmallLogoUrl, VisitorID] @ [TeamSmallLogoUrl, HomeID]
Tuesday, 7:15pm [TeamSmallLogoUrl, VisitorID] @ [TeamSmallLogoUrl, HomeID]
Wednesday, 5:30pm [TeamSmallLogoUrl, VisitorID] @ [TeamSmallLogoUrl, HomeID]
...
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I create this in mvc3 as a list with selectable team logos so all the user has to do is click on the logo to make their pick. I also do not know if I have the database built up enough to make this happen. As of right now I have 2 tables Teams and Schedule.
    teams - teamid, teamsmalllogourl
    schedule - gameid, week, date, time, visitorid, visitorscore, homeid, homescore

Another question: Will I absolutely need jquery to accomplish something like this?

So as it stands if anyone can give me some guidance or send me an example I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a grid control for mvc3? If so, is there a grid I can use that is free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a grid. I suggest you to use jquery so you can work on the "client-side" so you can reduce the amount of data that go from the server to the client.

Look at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx). It give you an example on how to use a grid with JQuery